# Exporting an HTML table to PDF with text alignment

Tags: html, css, pdf, jspdf

I'm wondering if there is a way to export also the alignment of the text using the jsPDF. In exporting excel files its easier because it accepts the inline css of the table but in exporting the table to pdf, the alignment are all in the left. This is my script:

```
    <script>
    function demoFromHTML() {
        $(document).find('tfoot').remove();

        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
        // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
        source = $('#table')[0];

        // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
        // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
        // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
        // (class, of compound) at this time.
        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 85,
            width: 522
        };
        // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
        // 'inches' in this case
        pdf.fromHTML(
        source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, { // y coord
            'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },

        function (dispose) {
            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            var name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
            pdf.save(name);
        }, margins);
        setTimeout("window.location.reload()",0.0000001);

    }
    </script>
```

And my table looks like this:

```
 <div id="table">
    <table data-filter="#filter" class="footable" style="background-color:white;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Branch Code</th>
                <th>Client ID</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Report Timestamp</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
            if(count($result)==0)
            { echo "<tr><td colspan='5' style='text-align:center; font-weight:bold;'>No data available</td></tr>"; }
            else
            {
            for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){?>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">1</td>
                <td align="left">2</td>
                <td align="left">3</td>
                <td align="right">4</td>
                <td align="left">5</td>
            </tr>

            <?php }
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">
                    <div class="pagination pagination-centered"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alignment on Table's cells is not supported by default in jsPDF at the moment. Instead, you can use a third-part library such as HTMLTable[1] to do it.

[1] : https://github.com/ArtBIT/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.plugin.htmltable.js

Comment: How will I implement that? Am I only gonna write it like this? `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.plugin.htmltable.js"></script>`

Comment: In the script I can see under the  jsPDFAPI.setStyle = function(name, value) {align} How will I do that?